# Как форматировать JSON не в одну строку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, файлы, форматирование

При использовании файла `.json` (в моем случае **python3**, модуль **json**) в другой программе после сохранения командой `json.dump(python_dict, json_file)`, если потом открыть самостоятельно файл `.json`, то он будет в виде одной огромной строки (2000+ символов).

Есть ли варианты это исправить?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуйте в файл записывать `json.dump` с параметром `indent`:

```
import json

with open("my_file.json", "w") as json_file:
    json.dump(python_dict, json_file, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

в итоге для такого словаря:

```
python_dict = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [{'c': [456, 789, 123]}, {'d': 'e'}]}
```

файл будет выглядеть примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот я всегда в замешательстве, зачем представлять json в таком виде? Да, я понимаю, что на начальном этапе (учебе) это может и надо. А, затем, кто открывает JSON в редакторе, чтобы его почитать? Так еще после какое нибудь звено в ПО откажется понимать все эти переводы строк и кучу пробелов. Не критика, просто наболело=)

Comment: @Дмитрий не смогу ответить на ваш вопрос, свои json пакую сам, потому знаю, что в них и на каком уровне вложенности )) возможно, у автора чисто акдемический интерес

Comment: Ну просто пару раз в процессе разработки нужно все-таки пару раз залезть :)

Comment: @Дмитрий json и был задуман для возможно чтения людьми в ущерб производительности и компактности. Все эти переводы строк и кучи пробелов, если они по правилам слеланы, нормальный парсер (RFC 8259) нормально прочитает.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan да, [вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1281986/209304) уже разбирался с данным вопросом