# JSON формат, а стоит ли его читать?

Tags: javascript, python, json

Сегодня был задан [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1281719/209304) на *ruSO* и касается отображения файла JSON в удобочитаемом варианте для человека. Вопрос занял мою голову на весь день, да, и отрицать популярность данного формата на сегодняшний день глупо. Поговорил с коллегами, попытался узнать: кто-нибудь в реальных задачах применяет `pretty-printed` JSON-файлы. Ответ оказался отрицательным. Но нашлись примеры борьбы с излишним количеством знаков у `front-end` разработчиков на `javascript` и это вроде как рутинная обработка и они не обращают внимание на это.

Поскольку вышеуказанный вопрос касался непосредственно `python`, я полез читать что же написано в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) по этому поводу, а точнее параметра `indent`. И вот что там:

> .... and object members will be **pretty-printed** with that indent level.

Да, я допускаю, что представление структуры JSON в виде иерархии очень показательно при обучении, но после программисты продолжают использовать данные с кучей пробелов и переводами строк. Пример из последнего: один товарищ пытается отослать команды на кастомную PLC систему (она принимает JSON, но что под капотом у нас доступа нет) и возмущается, что ничего не работает. Чистим JSON -> все работает.

Как я это вижу и почему я не хочу читать данные файлы глазами. Все дело в том, что дальнейшая обработка полученных данных заключена в работе с простым словарем (в терминологии `python`). И в любом случае я буду перебирать `ключ:значение`. Я могу узнать у словаря существует ли ключ, какой тип данных лежит под этим ключем, забрать данные, поместить данные и т.д.

Поскольку я постоянно с этим сталкиваюсь и мне приходится подчищать и обрабатывать такого типа файлы, возникает вопрос: существует ли реальная задача (здесь я понимаю "не учебная"), где необходимо было бы использовать красоту в иерархии JSON-файла? Может кто-то сталкивался? Может быть я действительно чего-то не замечаю.

Comment: Ну не скажу за питон и яваскрипт, а в MySQL правильно написать разбор сложного JSON/ не имея перед глазами пример данных, в котором хорошо видна структура - занятие не для слабонервных. *дальнейшая обработка полученных данных заключена в работе с простым словарем (в терминологии python). И в любом случае я буду перебирать ключ:значение* Ну-ну, когда у тебя 4-5 уровней вложенности, и массивы с объектами вперемешку.. может, только итерационное мышление тебя и спасает.

Comment: Каждый первый фронтендер использует `package.json` самый натуральный pretty-printed JSON-файл

Comment: Иногда JSON файлы - часть UI. Приходится редактировать их в текстовом редакторе. В этой ситуации работать с одной многокилобайтной строкой невозможно.

Comment: Почти любой мало-мальски продвинутый текстовый редактор имеет возможности автоформатирования и подсветки синтаксиса. Открываем в нём неформатированный json - получаем удобный вид. / А гонять по сети и хранить следует json в компактном виде.

Comment: @Akina проблема вложенности - всегда минус. Не силен `MySQL`, но похоже действительно надо иметь перед глазами структуру. Здесь возникает другой вопрос, а если вложенность много больше 4-5 уровней? это тоже становится проблемой даже со структурой перед глазами

Comment: Notepad++, с его способностью сворачивать узлы, при правильном форматировании вполне приятный для таких дел инструмент.

Comment: @Дмитрий, мне кажется вы рассматриваете данный параметр немного в черно-белой плоскости. Представьте себе, что вы получаете от одного сервиса JSON в одну строку и все у вас OK. Но разработчики сервиса решили его "улучшить" и ваша система сломалась. Так вот даже для того, чтобы понять что случилось, уже будет полезно __временно__ воспользоваться параметром `indent` для отладки. Некоторые "любители" также выбирают pritty-printed JSON как формат хранения конфигурационных файлов. Лично я предпочитаю YAML формат для конфигов.

Comment: В общем я могу себе представить несколько сценариев когда это может пригодиться...

Comment: Еще один пример, если json часть кода: тестовые данные, спецификация API или конфигурация. Делать code review неотформатированного json/xml ужасно неудобно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как по любому вопросу, который засел в голове, пришлось провести мини-исследование. Темой которого стало: "Нужен ли `pretty-printed` JSON?" Для ленивых сразу спойлер - мой ответ: "Да, нужен". Отправной точкой стали комментарии оставленные под вопросом.

Итак, по порядку:

1. JSON - текстовый формат обмена данными, основанный на JavaScript. Как и многие другие текстовые форматы, JSON легко читается людьми. [Wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). Основой стал `XML`, а цель создать облегченную версию формата обмена данными. Т.е. изначально закладывалась идея возможности чтения без различных кодировщиков и интерпретаторов.
2. JSON позволяет легко читать структуру запросов\ответов к API. Да, в документации к различным API содержатся структуры запросов именно в `pretty-printed` JSON. Это действительно удобно и сокращает время на создание\понимание запросов. (по мотивам комментария от Roman Konovalov)
3. Конфигурации. Здесь не все так однозначно и есть противники использования JSON формата для конфиг файлов, но `ASP.Net core` [использует](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0), а также нашел еще парочку открытых примеров. Но очень расстроился, когда понял, что пример лежит перед самым носом. VSCode позволяет конфигурировать себя с помощью JSON, черт. <kbd>F1</kbd>->`Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`. Удобно, ли, читать и форматировать? Естественно. (по мотивам комментариев от Roman Konovalov, MaxU)
4. Различного рода отладка. Здесь я остался при том мнении, что читать я не буду. Получение данных и дальнейшая обработка - задачи, которые решаются при помощи написания кода. Отлавливать глазами, а потом писать обработку? Можно, же, сразу писать обработку, реализовывать исключения для непонятных данных и проч. Но чтобы к этому прийти, сдается мне, что по началу я тоже читал глазами.
5. Для самого `pythona` нашел библиотеку для использования переменных сред из JSON файла. [json-environ](https://json-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html). Удобство чтения и использования на лицо. Вряд ли лучшее решение для меня, но все же.

Для баз данных ничего интересного не нашел кроме того, что функционал различных DB поддерживается для работы с JSON ([postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-json.html), [SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)). Насколько необходимо иметь красивый JSON, не понятно.

Что по итогу:

Вопрос изначально не был состоятельным. Если закладывают в формат на старте возможность, зачем в принципе это отрицать. Если я не использую `pretty-printed` JSON - это абсолютно не значит, что никому это не нужно. Но полностью согласен, что *"... гонять по сети и хранить следует json в компактном виде"* (Alexander Petrov).